# Can some explain how the following code works?

Tags: haskell

I am doing a coding challenge in codewar: Write function avg which calculates average of numbers in given list. My solution works but I don't quite understand one of the solutions of others. Can anyone explain?

```
avg :: [Float] -> Float
avg = (/) <$> sum <*> fromIntegral . length
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
avg l = pure (/) <*> sum l <*> fromIntegral . length  $ l
```

Comment: Isn't it a *challenge* for you, not us?

Comment: You can also write it as `liftA2 (/) sum (fromIntegral . length)`

Comment: `pure f <*> x = f <$> x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code uses the `Applicative` instance of the `(->) a` type, which is defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-697) as:

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

You can interpret this implementation by thinking of `naryFunction <$> f1 <*> f2 <*> ... <*> fn` as "apply the same parameter to all n functions and apply the resulting arguments to `naryFunction`".

In your case, `(/) <$> sum <*> fromIntegral . length` can be thought as `\ xs ->
 (/) (sum xs) ((fromIntegral . length) xs)` which is just `sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)`.

You can prove this by simply expanding your expression with the definition of `(<*>)`:

```
avg = (/) <$> sum <*> fromIntegral . length
avg = fmap (/) sum <*> fromIntegral . length
avg xs = (fmap (/) sum) xs ((fromIntegral . length) xs)
avg xs = ((/) . sum xs) (fromIntegral (length xs))  -- fmap f g = f . g
avg xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)
```